# Split a string by some separator in bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I would like to split a string into substrings, separated by some separator (which is also a string itself).

How can I do that

- using bash only? (for minimalism, and my main interest)
- or If allowing some  text processing program? (for convenience when the program is available)

Thanks.

Simple example,

- split `1--123--23` by `--` into `1`, `123` and `23`.
- split `1?*123` by `?*` into `1` and `123`

Comment: Could you show an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: With a fixed number of substrings, or variable?

Comment: No. The number of substrings in the result depends on the original string and the separator. @JeffSchaller

Comment: It wasn't a true/false question, I was asking what type of input you're asking about.

Comment: You're better off using the external programs (`sed`, `awk`) that are *precisely* designed for such text processing.  But that's for practicality and getting things done.  If this is a question of academic interest as I suspect it is, of course, that wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pure bash solution, using `IFS` and `read`. Note that the strings shouldn't contain `$'\2'` (or whatever else you use for IFS, unfortunately `$'\0'` doesn't work, but e.g. `$'\666'` does):

```
#!/bin/bash

split_by () {
    string=$1
    separator=$2

    tmp=${string//"$separator"/$'\2'}
    IFS=$'\2' read -a arr <<< "$tmp"
    for substr in "${arr[@]}" ; do
        echo "<$substr>"
    done
    echo
}


split_by '1--123--23' '--'
split_by '1?*123' '?*'
```

Or use Perl:

```
perl -E 'say for split quotemeta shift, shift' -- "$separator" "$string"
```

Comment: +1.  personally, i'd have separator as the first arg, same as perl.  also allows looping over all remaining args and splitting them too: `separator="$1" ; shift ; for string in "$@" ; do ... ; done`

Comment: FYI, i wrote a join function for bash because I missed it from perl.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299362/7696

Comment: Thanks. Is the purpose of `tmp=${string//"$separator"/$'\2'}` to replace a separator `$separator` which might be more than one character long to a separator `\2` just one character in length? If yes, why isn't it rewritten as `tmp=${string/"$separator"/'\2'}` instead? What do `//` and `/$` mean?

Comment: @Tim: exactly. That's how IFS works.

Comment: @Tim: `'\2'` are 2 characters, `$'\2'` is one. `//` is global replace, see Parameter Expansion in `man bash`.

Comment: Thanks. What does `$` before`'\2'` mean?

Comment: @Tim: It interprets `\2` as the ASCII 02. See "Quoting" in `man bash`.

Answer (score 7):

Simply with **awk**:

```
str="1--123--23"
awk -F'--' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' <<< $str
```

The output:

```
1
123
23
```

---

Another short ***Python*** solution:

`splitter.py` script:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.argv[2].split(sys.argv[1])))
```

---

arguments order:

- `sys.argv[0]` - script name (i.e. `splitter.py`)
- `sys.argv[1]` - substring separator
- `sys.argv[2]` - input string

Usage:

```
python splitter.py "?*" "1?*123"
1
123
```

---

```
python splitter.py "--" "1--23--123"
1
23
123
```

Comment: But not pure `bash`. Nice solution though.

Comment: I found the awk expression helpful. Thanks!

Comment: this helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

Pure POSIX shell:

```
string="1--123--23"
del="--"

while test "${string#*$del}" != "$string" ; do
  echo "${string%%$del*}"
  string="${string#*$del}"
done
echo "$string"
```

Note that `*` or `?` need to be escaped in the delimiter: `del='\*'`

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash
#  (GPL3+) Alberto Salvia Novella (es20490446e)


substring () {
    string=${1}
    separator=${2}
    position=${3}

    substring=${string//"${separator}"/$'\2'}
    IFS=$'\2' read -a substring <<< "${substring}"
    echo ${substring[${position}]}
}


substring ${@}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above but say you just want to get the URI for example:

```
URL="http://something.com/backup/v/photos/path/to/"
URI="./$(echo $URL | awk -F'.com/' '{print $2}')"
echo $URI
```

Comment: There already is an `awk` solution that even better addresses the problem.

Comment: These other ones didn't really work for me so I just wanted to share something I was trying to do .. Is this not useful ?

Comment: The question was to cut a string into an unknown number of parts. Yours does only cut the last piece of the string and could be replaced by a simple `URI="${URL#*.com}"`

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Briefly, `split` destructively removes a separator, which can be defined using a regex pattern:

```perl
~$ echo "string1_sep_string2" | raku -ne '.split(/ _sep_ /).put;'
```

Output:

```
string1 string2
```

You can also `join` after `split`-ting:

```perl
~$ echo "string1_sep_string2" | raku -ne '.split(/ _sep_ /).join(",").put;'
```

Output:

```
string1,string2
```

To look at the resultant elements one-per-line, iterate over the output with `for`.  Adding `perl` or `raku` to the output call double-quotes the output, indicating that Raku understands the elements to be strings:

```perl
~$ echo "string1_sep_string2" | raku -ne '.raku.put for .split(/ _sep_ /);'
```

Output:

```
"string1"
"string2"
```

Note: you'll occasionally run into issues were empty strings remain after `split`-ting. These are removed by adding `:skip-empty` to the `split` call, as in `.split(/ _sep_ /, :skip-empty`)`. See examples below.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/split
https://raku.org