# What does `$` in `$'\2'` mean?

Tags: bash

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378549/674

```
tmp=${string//"$separator"/$'\2'}
```

What does `$` in `$'\2'` mean?

Is `$'\2'` a parameter expansion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

`$'\2'` is expanded to the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value 2. In the answer you refer to, this character is used as a field separator.

Comment: Thanks. In C language, how is `$\2` specified instead?

Comment: `$` introduces the string in Bash, it has no special meaning in C; if you wanted to store the string `$\2` in C, you’d just escape the backslash, `$\\2`.

Comment: Thanks. In C, how is the octal value 2 specified? Is it `0x2`? Is there a similar metacharacter in C to `$`  in Bash?

Comment: In C, in a numeric context you just use a leading 0 for an octal value, so 010 is 8; in a string context with a backslash, values are treated as octal anyway. There’s no need for a `$`-style metacharacter, backslashes are interpreted in this way in all C strings: you’d just write `"\2"`.