# Splitting a string by another string or substring in Bash

Tags: bash

I was reviewing this post: [Split a string by some separator in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378547/split-a-string-by-some-separator-in-bash)

In my scenario, I tried to use just Bash to accomplish this, but I'm running into some weird behavior.

```
shopt -s extglob
export var=abc_def__123__456
echo ${var/%__*}
echo ${var/#!(__)__}
shopt -u extglob
```

The first `echo` is working as expected and outputs `abc_def`.  I'm expecting the second `echo` to output `123__456` and instead, it outputs `456`.  This is not working the way I'm reading [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), which says:

> If *pattern* is preceded by ‘#’ (the third form above), it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of *parameter*.

To me, this means that when it gets to the first occurrence of `__`, the match should stop and so the second `echo` should return `123__456`, which is desired.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any POSIX shell, using standard [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
var="abc_def__123__456"
echo "${var%%__*}"
echo "${var#*__}"
```

Output:

```
abc_def
123__456
```

Comment: Ok, I saw that and didn't know if `*` was going to be greedy like `.*` is in regex.

Comment: Ah, but I guess that's what `#` signifies (not greedy/shortest match) and `%%` makes it greedy from the right to left.  Thank you!

Comment: @Hossy `#` and `%` removes the shortest prefix and suffix string (respectively) matching the given shell pattern. If you double them up as `%%` and `##`, they remove the longest prefix and suffix string matched by the given pattern.