# Checking if a variable defined by another variable exists in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) but I'm trying to adapt it to my case where I don't hardcode the variable name.  In fact, I'm combining logic from a [previous question of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741146/splitting-a-string-by-another-string-or-substring-in-bash).

Something like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
export var=abc_def__123__456
echo ${var/%__*}
# does this variable (abc_def) exist?
echo This is not valid syntax: [ -z ${${var/%__*}+x} ] && echo ${var/%__*} does not exist
echo Effectively checking this: [ -z ${abc_def+x} ] && echo abc_def does not exist
shopt -u extglob
```

EDIT (answer from @ikkachu):

```
shopt -s extglob
export var=abc_def__123__456
# does this variable (abc_def) exist?
if [[ ! -v ${var/%__*} ]]; then echo ${var/%__*} does not exist; fi
# does this variable (abc_def) exist? (with temp variable)
export temp=${var/%__*}
echo ${temp}
if [ ! -z ${temp+x} ]; then echo \'temp\' exists; fi # checks temp variable only
if [ -z ${!temp+x} ]; then echo ${temp} does not exist; fi
if [ -z ${abc_def+x} ]; then echo abc_def does not exist; fi
shopt -u extglob
```

Additional information (from [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)):

> When not performing substring expansion, using the form described below (e.g., ‘:-’), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both *parameter’s* existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash in particular, you can use `[[ -v var ]]`:

```
$ foo=1; unset bar;
$ varname=foo
$ if [[ -v $varname ]]; then echo set; else echo not set; fi
set
$ varname=bar
$ if [[ -v $varname ]]; then echo set; else echo not set; fi
not set
```

Works with e.g. `[[ -v ${var/%__*} ]]` too.

Or you can use "alternate value" expansion with a nameref (but you need that temporary variable):

```
$ declare -n ref=foo
$ if [[ ${ref+set} = set ]]; then echo set; else echo not set; fi
set
$ declare -n ref=bar
$ if [[ ${ref+set} = set ]]; then echo set; else echo not set; fi
not set
```

Or the same with the `${!var}` indirect expansion, i.e. `${!var+set}` etc.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't seem to find the reference for the alternate value expansion.  Do you happen to have a link or could point me to something to search for?

Disregard it, just read the Bash manual more. :-)

Comment: @Hossy, this is a case where the POSIX text is perhaps easier to read than Bash's manual, at least they have a nice table of all the cases: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02